# Unable to load the service index for source https://nuget.sitecore.com/resources/v3/index.json

Tags: docker

Recently I updated Nuget feed with new Sitecore public url https://nuget.sitecore.com/resources/v3/index.json.

It works fine in Visual studio build but when I build my solution within docker using msbuild, it throws errro  NU1301: Unable to load the service index for source https://nuget.sitecore.com/resources/v3/index.json.

I tried few things like:
1-  Set-PSRepository -Name SitecoreGallery -InstallationPolicy Trusted -SourceLocation https://nuget.sitecore.com/resources/v3
2- Updated the nuget url in init.ps1 parameter $SitecoreGalleryRepositoryLocation = "https://nuget.sitecore.com/resources/v3",

But it did not work. Any idea how to fix it?

[image]

Comment: Did u refer the solution recommended here - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1308285/visual-studio-docker-error-nu1301-unable-to-)-load

Comment: Yes, I already have those settings:{
  "dns": [
    "10.1.2.3",
    "8.8.8.8"
  ],
  "experimental": true
}

Comment: If you shell into your container, can you ping any external urls? Make sure that those DNS settings are being used.

Answer (score 0):

The error `NU1301: Unable to load the service index for source https://nuget.sitecore.com/resources/v3/index.json` you are experiencing during the Docker build, while not during the Visual Studio build, suggests that there might be an issue with the network configuration, permissions, or the way NuGet is set up within your Docker container. Here are a few steps you might consider to troubleshoot and resolve this issue:

1. **Check Network Configuration:**

   - Ensure that your Docker container has the necessary network access to reach the NuGet repository at `https://nuget.sitecore.com/resources/v3/index.json`.
   - You might also want to check if there are any proxy settings that need to be configured to allow the Docker container to access external resources.
2. **Check NuGet Configuration:**

   - Verify that the NuGet configuration within your Docker container is correctly pointing to the Sitecore NuGet repository.
   - You might need to add the NuGet source explicitly using a command like `nuget sources add -Name "Sitecore" -Source "https://nuget.sitecore.com/resources/v3/index.json"` in your Dockerfile.
3. **Check Dockerfile and Build Context:**

   - Ensure that your Dockerfile and build context are correctly set up, and that all necessary files, including the `NuGet.config` file, are available within the build context.
4. **Use a Custom NuGet.config:**

   - Create a custom `NuGet.config` file with the Sitecore NuGet repository configured, and ensure this file is used during the Docker build process.

These steps should help in identifying and fixing the issue. It might be a process of elimination to figure out the exact cause, but systematically going through these steps should get you closer to a resolution.